# UITableViewCell - prepareForReuse and dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

Check the [GitHub project](https://github.com/SlaunchaMan/GCDExample) for this [article](http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2011/02/28/cocoa-touch-tutorial-using-grand-central-dispatch-for-asynchronous-table-view-cells/).
A notification is sent by **prepareForReuse** method of the custom cell(JKCallbacksTableViewCell class) to the table(RootViewController class) which is observed by the **tableViewCellIsPreparingForReuse** method. This method resets the association key and the imageview of the cell.

So, why does author preferred to send it through a notification instead of resetting them after getting a non-nil cell from **dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier** method of the table?

According to the [documentation of UITableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/reuseIdentifier), prepareForReuse is called just before dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier.

> If a UITableViewCell object is reusable—that is, it has a reuse identifier—this method is invoked just before the object is returned from the UITableView method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:.

I have tested it that when dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returns a non-nill value it's coupled with a call to prepareForReuse.

Author commented in the JKCallbacksTableViewCell.h about application logic separation but i think that is a kind of overkill; optimizing performance with async dispatch but sending those slow notifications to reset some properties... Or am i missing something about GCD?

Comment: Have you tried to ask him directly ? He seems pretty active in the comment section of the article... He may know better than anyone else why he choose this method :) Maybe even send him a link to this question, he may come answer it, don't you think ?

Comment: well i consider this but comments closed. anyway i will look for ways to contact him.

Comment: Comments aren’t closed, they’re moderated. I’ll answer here in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most programming problems have a near-infinite number of solutions. I didn’t have any particular reason to choose notifications other than the fact that they’re loosely coupled.

Regarding your comment about the speed of the notification: the thing that makes the app slow is loading the images, so we’re trying to optimize *that*. Notifications aren’t slow enough to make a difference in the use of the app otherwise, so to use something else for pure performance reasons is unwarranted here.

That said, it’s in GitHub, so feel free to send a pull request that doesn’t use notifications. If I like it better, I’ll use it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. whatever, forget the performance consideration.i actually want to know if i will be doing smth(especially breaking smth with GCD) wrong by calling tableViewCellIsPreparingForReuse after a non-nill cell returned from deque..cell method.

Comment: No, that won’t break anything.